# Link href to JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a string & a GIF that displays when JS button is clicked 
I searched for hours looking for a solution but I unfortunately didnt find one,
here is the code:

```js
var currImage = 0;
window.onload = () => {
  const factsArr = [{
      image: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif',
      source: "know more"
    },
    {
      image: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/TvsLe5DV4gKCQ/giphy.gif',
      source: "know more"
    },
    {
      image: 'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif',
      source: "know more"
    },
  ];

  const swtch = () => {
    document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
    document.getElementById('source').innerHTML = factsArr[currImage].source;
    currImage++;
    if (currImage == factsArr.length)
      currImage = 0;
    console.log(currImage);
  };
  document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', swtch);
  document.getElementById('source').addEventListener('click', swtch);
}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<div id="source"></div>
<img id="image" />
```

I want to add the link to "Know more".

Comment: So `source: "<a href='http://example.com'>Know More</a>"` ??? Or you wanted to add a property in your object? If so, change the div to an anchor and set the href like you do for innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Either put HTML into the source

```js
var currImage = 0;
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif', source:"<a href='https://www.example.com'>know more 1</a>" },
  { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/TvsLe5DV4gKCQ/giphy.gif', source:"<a href='https://www.example.com'>know more 2</a>" },
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif', source:"<a href='https://www.example.com'>know more 3</a>" },
    ];
 
 const swtch = () => {
    document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
    document.getElementById('source').innerHTML=factsArr[currImage].source;
    currImage++;
    if (currImage == factsArr.length)
        currImage = 0;
    console.log(currImage);
};
document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', swtch);
document.getElementById('source').addEventListener('click', swtch);
}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<div id="source"></div>
<img id="image" />
```

Or add a new property and change your html

```js
var currImage = 0;
window.onload = () => {
    const factsArr = [
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7aD5tv1ogNBtDhDi/giphy.gif', source:"know more", href: "https://www.example.com" },
  { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/TvsLe5DV4gKCQ/giphy.gif', source:"know more", href: "https://www.example.com" },
 { image:'https://media.giphy.com/media/1nkUav308CBws/giphy.gif', source:"know more", href: "https://www.example.com" },
    ];
 
 const swtch = () => {
    document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', factsArr[currImage].image);
    const out =  document.getElementById('source');
    out.innerHTML=factsArr[currImage].source;
    out.href=factsArr[currImage].href;
    currImage++;
    if (currImage == factsArr.length)
        currImage = 0;
    console.log(currImage);
};
document.getElementById('generate-btn').addEventListener('click', swtch);
document.getElementById('source').addEventListener('click', swtch);
}
```

```html
<button id="generate-btn">Amazing Fact Button</button>
<div><a id="source"></a></div>
<img id="image" />
```